# Wrong/corrupted icon in dash

Tags: unity, icons

I am facing a problem with the dash not showing proper/actual icons for certain applications such as Google Chrome and Mozilla Daily Mail. Instead of getting the standard icons for these applications, I get to see a default icon for all the applications. I have added a snapshot to show the problem.

The icons that are shown in the launcher once launched or in the /usr/share/applications directory are proper. I have tried rebuilding the icon cache, but that did not help. I have also tried switching to other icons themes. This issue does not appear with Gnome Shell or KDE.

I have also tried deleting ~/.local/share/applications/menu-xdg, there was none in the first place.

I am using Ubuntu 12.10. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is now resolved. Unfortunately, I am not sure how. The last thing I did was deleting the `~/.local/share/applications`, but it had no menu-xdg.